# Jquery redirect to another page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to make an update status button which it's submited by ajax, but every single time when I update the status I get redirected on `base_url().'/Admin/Jobs/'`. It's possible to update the status without getting that redirect?

Code:

```
<?php if ($key['status'] === '1'): ?>
<?php echo form_open('Admin/update_job_status'); ?>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $key['id'] ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="status" value="0">
<button class="btn btn-success btn-simple" id="submit" rel="tooltip" title="Status Active">
    <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
</button>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit').on('click', function(){
            var formData = {
            'id'  : $('#id').val(),
            'status'    :      $('#status').val()
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                data: formData,
                url: '<?php echo base_url().'/Admin/Jobs/' ?>',
                success: function(data){
                    alert(id);
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<?php endif ?>

<?php if (is_null($key['status']) || $key['status'] === '0'): ?>
<?php echo form_open('Admin/update_job_status'); ?>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $key['id'] ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="status" value="1">
<button class="btn btn-warning btn-simple" rel="tooltip" title="Status Inactive">
    <i class="fas fa-eye-slash "></i>
</button>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit').on('click', function(){
            var formData = {
            'id'  : $('#id').val(),
            'status'    :      $('#status').val()
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                data: formData,
                url: '<?php echo base_url().'/Admin/Jobs/' ?>',
                success: function(data){
                    alert(id);
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You submit event is sent, because it is not stopped. You have to use [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to prevent "natural" form submit.

```
    $('#submit').on('click', function(event) { // add event parameter
       event.preventDefault(); // stop form submit
       //...
```

Comment: @TerchilăMarian Do you have a JavaScript error (in console)?

Comment: I dont have anything

Answer (score 0):

A button in a form by default is a submit button and if you click on it it will post your form back to the specified url.
You can explicitly set your button to be a normal button by setting the type attribute to button

```
<button type="button"...
```

or you can prevent the form from submitting via JavaScript in the event handler

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();// prevents the default action, which is submitting the html form
   ...
```

Comment: When I change the type it's not submitting anymore

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#submit').on('click', function(){ 
      var formData = { 
            'id' : $('#id').val(), 
            'status' : $('#status').val() 
      } 
     $.ajax({ 
         type: 'post', 
         data: formData, 
         url: '<?php echo base_url().'/Admin/Jobs/' ?>', 
         success: function(data)  { alert(id); }, 
      }); 

      return false; // disable form submit

  }); });
```

Comment: It's still redirecting

Comment: Oh, i thought at first you attach the event handler on form element.
If you want to prevent form submit when the button is clicked, just add attribute type="button" to your button

Comment: I've done that but now the form it's not submitting anymore